# Microsoft Word 2010 heading from the page beginning

Tags: microsoft-word

How to set on MS word 2010 that heading 1 or heading 2 start from the first available page beginning?

EDIT: I am not thinking on heading.
E.g. I want this automatically without need of me to press enter.

[image]

I don't want this:

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the header? Your question isn't clear. Can you give us some more info? Screenshot?

Comment: @skub I edited the question with pictures.

Comment: Add a page break before each header.

Comment: @JohnDR Tnx, that's what I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the heading to always start a new page, edit the Heading 1 and Heading 2 styles.
[image: Styles Pane]

Open the Paragraph Format Window:
[image: Modify Style Window]

In Paragraph settings, select Page Break Before.
[image: Paragraph Settings Window]

Then be sure to use the Heading 1 and Heading 2 styles.

Answer (score 1):

I usually set the heading style to "keep with next paragraph" and the default paragraph style to an appropriate widow-orphan tolerance (e.g. don't split).

see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/control-pagination-HP005189545.aspx

> You can control where Microsoft Word positions automatic page breaks by setting pagination options.

This often works better than inserting arbitrary page breaks. When adding text to an earlier paragraph you don't get blank pages or other odd pagination effects.